# About lvalues when it comes to assigning char array to another char array variable

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having a problem when i was programming with turbo c++ 4.5 when it comes to assigning a char array value to another one as another char array value as a string but it comes with a error

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    char txt[16],st[30],w[100];
    int i;

i = 0;
while((txt[i++]=getch())!='$');
    i--;
    st[i] = '\0';
    i=0;
while(txt[i]!='$')
{
    w = txt;
    i++;
}
txt[i] = '\0';
cout <<txt;
if (w == "h"){
cout << " the pass word is:"<<txt;
}
else
{
    cout << "incorrect";
}

}
```

Error mentioned in TC 4.5:

> Lvalue required in function main()

The error points it to where `w` is being assigned to `txt`.

Comment: actually , this is running in turbo c++ , so std was not defined that time

Comment: use other compiler then, any reason you are using legacy turbo c++ compiler?

Comment: You cannot assign arrays. You could write a loop to copy the elements, or use `memcpy` for that.

Comment: @Anonyme132: That was almost twenty years ago. Time to upgrade.

Comment: what is the problem in using an old compiler?they dont make much difference with new ones execpt with additional libraries but there aint much difference in syntax right?

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to use arrays as if they were a single variable. In C++ they are not. To copy an array you have to copy it member by member. To compare it with another array, you have to compare it member by member.

You could fix the error you have by switching

```
 w = txt;
```

to

```
w[i] = txt[i];
```

but unfortunately this won't make your code work the way you want it to (it will compile at least).
The easier way to make your code work is to rewrite it to work with strings instead of arrays, because they will behave the way you were expecting arrays to. You can use a string as a single variable.

If for any reason you want to keep the arrays, I suggest you write a function to compare two of them, like so:

```
bool equals_strings(char * s1, char * s2){
    for (int i = 0;; i++){
        if (s1[i] != s2[i])
            return false;

        if (s1[i] == '\0')      // I checked above that they are the same, only need to check one
            return true;
   }
}
```

and use it in your code:

```
void main()
{
    char txt[16], st[30], w[100];
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((txt[i++] = getch()) != '$');
    i--;
    st[i] = '\0';
    i = 0;
    while (txt[i] != '$')
    {
        w[i] = txt[i];
        i++;
    }
    txt[i] = '\0';
    cout << txt;
    if (equals_strings("hello", txt)){      // <- Used it here!
        cout << " the pass word is:" << txt;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "incorrect";
    }
}
```

**Be advised:** this kind of code in C++ is deadly and will lead you into all kinds of troubles. Have fun! :D